# CSS positioning: bottom of box right on top of box with hidden overflow

Tags: html, css, positioning

OK I have this in the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="help_box">some text</div>
    <div id="unique_title">Some Title<div class="help">?</div>
</div>
```

I also have a JS that when the mouse hovers over the **"?"**, the **"help_box"** becomes visible. What I want is to put the very bottom of the **"help_box"** right on top of the **"wrapper"** div. **I cannot write the "help_box" outside the wrapper. It must stay inside the "wrapper".**

Here is the CSS for the **"wrapper"** and the **"help_box"**:

```
.help_box {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 6px 5px;
    top: -30px;
    display: none;
    right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(51, 34, 170);
    border: 1px solid rgb(15, 27, 160);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.wrapper {
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: none !important;
    width: auto !important;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
}
```

Some **"help_box"** es have different heights. So although the box goes on top and looks beautiful within one line, it overlaps inside the **"wrapper"** if it has 2+ lines. So in my CSS, the **"top"** declaration is controlling only the top of my **"help_box"** div. How can I control the BOTTOM of this div?

I tried instead of **"top: -30px"**, I used: **"bottom: +200px"** but then the **"wrapper"** div is also varied in size.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgLNy/ I put the help_box instead the help class, so that I could trigger it to appear with css, and not bother with js.

Comment: @bozdoz - Can there be a delay trigger on this? Otherwise I have to use JS. It must be delayed.

Comment: Look into css transitions

Comment: That's really cool and I'll keep this in mind next time I code. However that's not my issue. The real issue I'm having is when I get some funky positioning when the "help_box" is over 1 line. http://jsfiddle.net/kgLNy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the help_box inside the help class, and add position relative to the help class; then adjust the `bottom` attribute, and not the `top`:

```
#help_box {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 6px 5px;
    bottom: 42px;
    display: none;
    right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(51, 34, 170);
    border: 1px solid rgb(15, 27, 160);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.help {
    position:relative;
}
.help:hover #help_box {
  display:block;   
}

#wrapper {
    top:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: none !important;
    width: auto !important;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/kgLNy/2/

Comment: I had to make the **"unique_title"** position to relative, but aside from that it worked PERFECTLY. Thank you.